MacOS default profile equivalent for VS Code
I'm taking an intermediate Python programming course and we will be using VS Code. As part of our workspace setup, the instructor asked we set up our 'settings.json' with the following:
{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
}

I modified the profile for MacOS:
{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "Command Prompt",
}

There was an error, 'Value is not accepted', for "Command Prompt"(see attached image). I reached out to my instructor and he wasn't sure of the correct fix, as he is unfamiliar with Mac machines.
After reviewing the VS Code site, I settled on updating the settings to the following and the error was eliminated:
{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": null,
}


My instructor suggested trying the following:
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "sh",
}

What is the correct way to set up the MacOS default profile that best matches the Windows default profile my instructor is wanting set up?
Value not accepted error

I don't think there is any reason to set this explicitly on your mac, because it's not going to be equivalent to "Command Prompt".

but it isn't clear, what is wrong with your instructor's suggestion of using "sh"? What exactly are you asking here?

On Mac you have one default terminals "zsh". In addition you also usually have "bash" and batch command runner like "sh".
All of them are good replacement for "Command Prompt", but neither of them use same notation in instructions. For example instruction dir from the Command prompt won't be working in "zsh". Instead of dir in mac terminal you use ls. And same for many other commands.
My suggestion would be to stick to ios zsh terminal and self learn the commands that will be equivalent to Windows "Command Prompt". Instructions that are used in zsh are similar to the ones used on any linux system. So they are more widespread and thus useful than the ones used in "Command Prompt". Please ask you tutor if he is familiar with linux terminals, linux instructions are more or less similar to the ones used on ios.
To sum up, to configure terminal on Mac use:
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh" 

As for the second setting, it was deprecated. Please don't use terminal.integrated.shell.osx

bash and sh also should be available on mac, but they are not default terminals.

Sorry, I didn't understand your point. If you wanted to note that instructions for "Command Prompt" won't be working on mac terminal, this is a good point.

yes, that's precisely the caveat I was suggesting!
